# shadow message in Wolfram Workbench 2.0

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, workbench

I am writing documentation for a package with WB 2.0.
Very often, when I create links or insert cells using the documentation tools palette, I get the following message:

Global`StyleNames::shdw: Symbol StyleNames appears in multiple contexts {Global`,System`}; definitions in context Global` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions. >>

This message appears even after I start a new session of Workbench - Mathematica.

Except for this, everything else seems to work fine. The documentation pages seem ok, although I have not yet made a "Build". Links, for ex, work as expected.

Can you explain why I get this message and how to fix it? 
Should I expect problems at the Build stage?

The only "hint" I can give (maybe irrelevant) is that the first time I created the symbol pages (automatically from the usage messages), WB got "confused" somehow and included the pages for the Numerical sample package which I downloaded from the Wolfram Workbench web site. I erased these symbol pages and eliminated any link/connection/extension relating to this Numerical package and since then everything seems ok, except for the above message.

---

I just experimented a little further with this problem and this is exactly what happens:

- Start WB 2.0
- In package explorer, doubleclick on a .nb file so that MMA is automatically started as default editor (I use the CardDeck.nb file in the CardDeck sample package found on Workbench site)
- When in MMA, open the DocumentationTools palette
- Click on the sample tutorial page button (or most other buttons for that matter)

Bang! I get the message:
Global`StyleNames::shdw: Symbol StyleNames appears in multiple contexts {Global`,System`}; definitions in context Global` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions. >>

in the message window.
So it seems that this problem is not related specifically to my package files, but is somehow linked to the DocumentationTools palette. 
Does anybody else have this problem? 
Is it a corrupted installation?

Thank you for any help

Comment: I am getting the Global`StyleNames::shdw: message too.  Probably a harmless warning message.  I imagine the shadowed definitions are the same as the reloaded ones.  Carry on and pay no attention.

Comment: @ChrisDegnen that's what I do. I was just wondering if this was a Workbench "bug" or a somehow incorrect installation.
It is harmless, as far as I can tell too.

Answer (score 1):

You could try switching off the automatic source loading for specific notebooks via Properties, Notebook Properties.