# Loading packages in a clean session in tutorial and symbol pages with Mathematica Workbench 2.0

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, workbench

I am developing documentation for a package with Workbench.
So far I have used

```
Quit[]
Needs["mypackage`"]
```

at the beginning of each Tutorial. This is because I want a clean global environment and package loading at the same time.

I ran some builds and everything worked as expected, but I wonder: is there a better way to have a clean global context and the package context load "automatically" each time a launch a tutorial for my package with MMA?

In other words: going from one tutorial to the next, or from a tutorial back to a regular MMA notebook, is it possible that all symbols defined in the tutorial examples be "forgotten"? In the standard MMA tutorial pages, this is what seems to happen.

I suppose this could be done this a local/notebook context.

But how would this work in practice?

Thank you for your help

Comment: @Brett or others: I have another old question on Workbench, which I just edited. But it does not seem to get the spotlight anymore.
So if you could please have a look at it, here is the link.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738057/shadow-message-in-wolfram-workbench-2-0

Thank you

Answer (score 9):

For each tutorial, choose the menu item **Evaluation > Notebook's Default Context > Unique to this Notebook**.  This will make each notebook have a new, unique, context.  So then you don't need the `Quit[]` (which seems like a pretty drastic method.)  There are probably a few ways you could make sure the `Needs` cell is run, but making it an initialization cell is probably the easiest.

Comment: something very strange happens: I have selected "Unique to this Notebook" context for my tutorials, made a build and then previewed the project. Well...it does not work! If i type a=10 in a tutorial cell, and then ?a, I get Global`a. Yet the correct "Unique to this Notebook" context is ticked in the Evaluation menu.

Comment: I was too quick to comment. Unfortunately things are not so clear.
Something very strange happens: I have selected "Unique to this Notebook" context for my tutorials, made a build and then previewed the project. Well...it does not work! If i type a=10 in a tutorial cell, and then ?a, I get Global`a. Yet the correct "Unique to this Notebook" context is ticked in the Evaluation menu.
Continue on the next comment

Comment: Continued from above.
On the other end in my guide page - which I think I did not change at all and which shows a Global` default context in the Evaluation menu - the same test works: I type a=10 ?a  and I get Cell$$xyz'a so the context is localized to a cell.
Also: if you check the tutorial
LightweightGridClient/tutorial/Introduction 
you will see that the above test works (you get Notebook$$xyz'a), yet the Evaluation menu shows a Global' default context.
So can anybody explain this?